# Failed while importing understand

Tags: python, dll, import, importerror

I am facing an error

```
import understand
```

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing understand : The specific module could not be found.
```

Can someone help?

Note : I have 32 bit of understand and 32 bit version of Python.

Comment: Please share the full traceback. It can contain some useful information

Comment: @Sujay this was the most recent traceback. It failed on line 1 itself while importing

Comment: It looks like you have a 64-bit installation of Python but a 32-bit installation of `understand` or vice versa. A  64-bit (or 32-bit) process on Windows cannot load a 32-bit (or 64-bit) DLL and will complain that it can't be loaded, or even say it isn't there when you can see it is.

Comment: I havent set it in environment,  by what name should I set it @Sujay

Comment: My windows is 32 bit and even python

Comment: @BoarGules could you please help?

Comment: The docs say *Python 3.8 and newer requires specifying the path to the Understand installation inside the script itself using the `os.add_dll_directory()` command*. Did you do that? *Before* the `import`?

Comment: @BoarGules can you share the reference of this. Should I add os_add command before importing in the script itself?

Comment: The reference is: https://support.scitools.com/t/getting-started-with-the-python-api/51 and yes, you *must* do it before importing `understand`, as the example makes clear.

Comment: Thanks @BoarGules this solved my problem:)